# Проверка инпутов на цифры и буквы на чистом js

Tags: javascript

У каждого инпута есть атрибут data-rule устанавливающий правила проверки на цифры и буквы. Задача в том чтобы при не верном заполнение инпута вылезало сообщение либо "Введите буквы" либо "Введите цифры" и работало автоматом без указания номера коллекции элемента ([0], [1] и тд). И соответственно сообщение об ошибке исчезало при исправление. Это основной вопрос.
И ещё один, возможно ли в эту функцию вставить валидацию на пустоту строки инпута?
Нужен код на чистом js.

```html
<form>
        <div class="one">
            <input type="text" data-rule="number">
            <div class="result"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="one">
            <input type="text" data-rule="number">
            <div class="result"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="one">
            <input type="text" data-rule="string">          
            <div class="result"></div>
        </div>
        <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

```js
function checkInputs() {
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-rule]');

    for(let input of inputs){
        input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
            let result = document.getElementsByClassName('result');
            let rule = this.dataset.rule;
            let value = this.value;
            let check;

            switch(rule){
                case 'number':
                check = /^\d+$/.test(value);
                break;

                case 'string':
                check = /^[a-zа-яё]+$/i.test(value);
                break;
            }

            if (check){
                this.classList.remove('invalid')
                this.classList.add('valid')
                result[0].remove()
                result[2].remove()
            }
            else{
                this.classList.remove('valid')
                this.classList.add('invalid')
                result[0].innerHTML= 'Введите цифры'
                result[2].innerHTML= 'Введите буквы'
            }
        });
    }
}

checkInputs()
```

```css
.valid {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

form {
    width: 10%;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Используйте атрибуты required, pattern и type=number - и вам вообще не понадобится ни единой строчки javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let check = {
  number: {err: 'Введите цифры!', reg: /^\d+$/},
  string: {err: 'Введите буквы!', reg: /^[a-zа-яё]+$/i},
}

function checkInputs() {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-rule]');
  let result = document.querySelectorAll('.result');

  for ( let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
      let rule = this.dataset.rule;
      let value = this.value;
      
      if( check[rule].reg.test( value ) && value ){
        // Если value - пустая строка, это false
        this.classList.remove('invalid');
        this.classList.add('valid');
        result[i].innerText = "";
        // Номер результата чудесным образом совпадает с номером инпута!)
      } else {
        this.classList.remove('valid');
        this.classList.add('invalid');
        result[i].innerText = check[rule].err;
      }
    });
    
    inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', function() {
      if( !this.value ) {
        result[i].innerText = "Поле не может быть пустым!";
      }
    });
  }
}

checkInputs();
```

```css
.one { margin: 5px; }
input[data-rule] { outline: none; }
.valid { border: 1px solid green; }
.invalid { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <input type="text" data-rule="number">
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>

<div class="one">
  <input type="text" data-rule="number">
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>

<div class="one">
  <input type="text" data-rule="string">
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: сразу вдогонку вопрос, если пользователь не начал ничего вводить, а сначала просто нажал на инпут и потом кликнул в другое место... нужно выводить сообщение "Поле не может быть пустым" ...

Comment: @MaxAkinshin Добавил blur )

Comment: ну и если я решу добавить новые правила проверки на емэйл например, то добавляю их в check?

Comment: @MaxAkinshin Угу)

Comment: Хочу подключить маску на проверку некоторых полей:
https://unpkg.com/imask
Как бы мне её встроить, чтобы при этом работали ошибки полей к которым она применима



function testPhone() {
    const el = document.querySelectorAll(".one");

    el.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
            IMask(
                item, {
                    mask: '+{7}(000)000-00-00',
                    lazy: false
                });
        });

    });
}

Comment: @MaxAkinshin Ну, регулярка для этой маски выглядит так `/^\+7\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/` — плюс 7, в скобках три любых числа `\d`, потом еще любые чила 3-2-2 шт. И всё без пробелов...

Comment: А можно добавить чтобы буквы не ввести было, только знак+ и цифры?
И получается дефис в ручную нужно вводить иначе не пропускает, можно ли добиться чтобы он автоматом появлялся в нужный момент(ну или уберу его вообще), с круглыми скобками такая же история что нужно в ручную, хотелось бы автоматом чтобы вводилось.